# ESP-IDF No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include/limits.h'

Tags: macos, clang, esp32

I've updated MacOS from 10.13 to 10.14 and then Xcode as well. So, clang now is 10.0.0 but it looks like my ESP-IDF projects are still referring to 9.0.0 that leads to crash of any `make` command:

No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include/limits.h'

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quiet easy - it requires to clean `kconfig` tool:

1. go to `tools/kconfig` under ESP-IDF
2. do `make clean`

projects now will build as before.